# Is it a good idea to use many namespaces in GAE datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, namespaces, datastore

I have about 500 folder entities to be stored in GAE.  I want to categorize them into 6 groups.  Can I use 6 different namespaces to distinguish them?  So that I create the entity using `new Entity(groupname, foldername);`

The other way is `new Entity("Folders", groupname+"/"+foldername);` so that they share one namespace but use different keynames.

I am wondering whether many namespaces take a lot of memory?  Which way is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if you will ever want folders in different namespaces to be returned in the same query.  You won't be able to do that with namespaces, you'll need to issue a separate query per namespace.